# Symfony Array passed from Twig to JS is always empty

Tags: javascript, twig

im trying to pass variables from Twig to a JS File to work with them.
No matter what I do the console log is always an empty array.
But that array is not empty as the dump shows.
What am I doing wrong?

PHP:

```php
$user = $this->getUser();

$markers = $doctrine->getRepository(Marker::class)->findBy(["relatedUser" => $user]);

return $this->render("map/index.html.twig", [
            "controller_name" => "MapController",
            "title" => "Map",
            "markers" => $markers
        ]);
```

HTML:

```html
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        var markers = '{{ markers|json_encode }}';
    </script>
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('mapLogic') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(window.markers));
});
```

Web Console:

[image]

Dump:

[image]

Here is the entire code from my Marker Entity.
But it does not implement JsonSerializabe:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MarkerRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MarkerRepository::class)]
class Marker
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'markers')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $relatedUser = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $geoData = [];

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRelatedUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->relatedUser;
    }

    public function setRelatedUser(?User $relatedUser): self
    {
        $this->relatedUser = $relatedUser;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGeoData(): array
    {
        return $this->geoData;
    }

    public function setGeoData(array $geoData): self
    {
        $this->geoData = $geoData;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `var markers = '{{ markers|json_encode }}';` look like when the page is generated if you right click on the page and choose "view source"? Looking at the web console, it looks like an array containing one object, just like it does in PHP, but with a bunch of default props and methods instead of the actual data.

Comment: @M.Eriksson `var markers = '[{}]';`

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump(json_encode($markers));` in your PHP, right before the `return`? Do you get the same then? If so, then we can exclude twig from the equation and focus on the entity you're trying to encode. It it implements "JsonSerializabe" interface, it can override the "normal" behavior when encoding. Good to know is that `json_encode()` only have access to public class properties as default.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yeah its exactly the same. `string(4) "[{}]"`. How is `dump(markers)` able to show me the correct array? From my understanding this should be wrong?

Comment: I added a bit more suggestions in my previous comment. It has to be something with the entities you're trying to encode.

Comment: @M.Eriksson i updated my question. But unfortunately it does not implement JsonSerializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the properties in your `Marker` entity are set to private, which means that they will be omitted when you encode it using `json_encode()`.

One way of solving it is to set all properties as `public` in that entity.

If you don't want to do that, there are another (and in my opinion, better) alternative. You can implement the `JsonSerializable` interface. Then you can decide what to serialize.

```
// Import the interface to the current namespace
use JsonSerializable;

// Now implement the interface
class Marker implements JsonSerializable
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'markers')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $relatedUser = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $geoData = [];

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt = null;

    // Now we need to implement the method defined in the interface.
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        // All you need to do here is to return the data you want to encode 
        // in the format you want.
        return [
            'id'          => $this->id,
            'relatedUser' => $this->relatedUser,
            'geoData'     => $this->geoData,
            'createdAt'   => $this->createdAt,
        ];
    }    

    // The rest of your object
```

Now it should return some actual data.

The manual for `JsonSerializable`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

The manual for `jsonSerialize()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php